# Useful features to learn in boost for immediate use

Tags: c++, boost

I know this could be seen as subjective off-the-cuff (thus a poor question), but bear with me.

Boost has recently become available on the project on which I'm working, and I don't have much experience with it. Boost has so many parts and features that it's hard to know where to get started in learning it - especially since I'll be trying to learn it while making production code.

So, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could list around 3 to 5 features which are very useful in general, every-day programming and state why they're useful.  I'm not asking you which is best, or trying to get a debate - I just want to know some good features to start learning and using immediately.  I don't need code samples either, I'll be more than happy to research how to use the features myself after I know which ones are sensible to start learning now.

I'll accept any answer with a concise list of features that are sensible :)

Comment: Boost is not a library, it is a collection of libraries. Why not look through [the list of libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/libraries.htm) and see what looks interesting to you?

Comment: What sorts of things are you doing in your target project? Just for example, ASIO could be really useful, but if you're not doing anything network related, it may not apply (at all).

Comment: How did I see that coming ^^, well thanks for the real answers to the people who tried :) guess I'll go post this one  on experts exchange for some feedback.

Comment: @w00te : Try [Programmers @ SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/); for the record, I voted to move the question there, not 'not constructive'.

Comment: Ah, I'll take a look at that :) and I appreciate you taking the time to make the suggestion.

Comment: For anyone interested in contributing to the discussion, the new thread the OP started is here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/112445/33100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`format` and `lexical_cast` are great for string manipulation, I find them invaluable.  I use them every day.

`bind` is great for ad hoc functors, you'll find it is reused throughout many of the boost libraries.

`multi_index` fills the gap of when you need the same data in two search structures at once, it is very handy at times.  Keep it out of your headers though.

`type_traits` defines useful traits for template specializations.

`signals` is a signal/slot mechanism implementation, great for event driven designs.

Comment: +1 for multi_index.  The syntax can be a bit cumbersome, but I've have found numerous uses for it recently.

Answer (score 1):

shared_pointer is critical. It lets you automatically handle memory usage.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm